# How do I limit a custom collection in 11ty to just posts, using `return collection.getAllSorted()`?

Tags: collections, eleventy

I have a custom collection in 11ty:

```
eleventyConfig.addCollection("recentPosts", function(collection) {
    return collection.getAllSorted().reverse().slice(0, 3);
});
```

That code is from here: https://tannerdolby.com/writing/create-a-custom-collection-with-eleventy/#filter-recent-posts

I'm trying to return just posts, sorted in reverse chronological order, and show only the last three. This works great, except that `getAllSorted` returns all content, not just posts. So how do I use this filter, but only get posts back?

My output I get is:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/_dist/index-bak/"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/_dist/posts/important-fourth-post-20230711/"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/posts/important-fourth-post-20230711/">The all important fourth post</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, it's getting the three latest pieces of modified content, not just the posts collection.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I should have used `getFilteredByGlob` rather than `getAllSorted`, in order to just pull the posts back. Here's what seems to work the way I want:

```
eleventyConfig.addCollection("recentPosts", function(collectionApi) {
  return collectionApi.getFilteredByGlob("./_src/posts/*.md").reverse().slice(0, 3);
});
```